# plotGoogleMaps help: plotting latitude longitude values

Tags: r, google-maps, geolocation, gis

I am trying to use plotGoogleMaps to plot latitude and longitude values

The code is:

```
streetCrime = read.csv("C:/Users/DAKSHA/Google Drive/BE Project/Daksha/Datasets/BaltimoreHomicide.csv")

coordinates(streetCrime) = ~Longitude + Latitude
proj4string(streetCrime) = CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")
m<-plotGoogleMaps(streetCrime,filename='myMap1.jpg')
```

I am getting this error:

```
Error in plotGoogleMaps(streetCrime, filename = "myMap1.jpg") :
   no slot of name "data" for this object of class "SpatialPoints"
```

Please help!

I am using plotGoogleMaps version 1.3

Comment: please post the output of `names(streetCrime)`

Comment: > names(streetCrime)
[1] "Latitude"  "Longitude"

> streetCrime <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(streetCrime,data = data.frame(ID = row.names(streetCrime)))


> names(streetCrime)
[1] "ID"

Comment: Yep, looks like it is as i suspected in my answer. So does plotGoogleMaps(streetCrime) work for you?!

Comment: After using SpatialPointsDataFrame, names(streetCrime) returns only ID. And when I trying setting coordinates I get this error: "setting coordinates cannot be done on Spatial objects, where they have already been set"

Comment: Why are you trying to set coordinates on something where the coordinates have already been set?! Please read my answer more carefully! All the correct steps are there. Follow these steps: 1) Read in your streetCrime data. 2) Set coordinates and projection info. 3) Turn into SpatialPointsDataFrame with command below. 4) Run plto command. Why are you trying to set coordinates again?

Comment: I have updated the answer with the exact steps for you to follow. You should be able to copy and paste, but I suggest you take some time to understand what you are doing more fully.

Comment: Great! Glad to help. I would advise spending some time getting familiar with the `sp` package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that your `.csv` contains only columns for `Latitude` and `Longitude` in which case the `coordinates()` function will return a `SpatialPoints` object rather than a `SpatialPointsDataFrame` which seems to be required of `plotGoogleMaps()`.

You can coerce it to an spdf by making a dummy varaible for the dataframe. An ID number for each point seems like a good idea. Try these steps in this order (please note that plotGoogleMaps saves the resulting plot as `html` not `jpg`):

```
streetCrime = read.csv("C:/Users/DAKSHA/Google Drive/BE Project/Daksha/Datasets/BaltimoreHomicide.csv")
coordinates(streetCrime) = ~ Longitude + Latitude
proj4string(streetCrime) = CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")
streetCrime <- SpatialPointsDataFrame( streetCrime , data = data.frame( ID = row.names( streetCrime ) ) )
m <- plotGoogleMaps(streetCrime , filename='myMap1.html')
```